# Tips for writing code for handling very large lists

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a large numpy array called `mylist`. I for each element in mylist (let's call it `mylist_element`) I want count how many `a <sqrt(mylist_element)` (`a>0`) are there, such that `sqrt(5*a**2 + 4 mylist_element`) is an integer.

For this I have written a code

```
import numpy as np

def is_square(x):
    # test for square root
    return x**.5 % 1 == 0

max = 10**5
mylist = np.arange(max)

def g(mylit_element):
    temporaryindex = 0
    a = 0
    while a <= mylit_element**.5:
        if is_square(5 *a**2 + 4* mylit_element):
            temporaryindex += 1
        a += 1
    if temporaryindex == 4:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


finalindex = np.sum(np.vectorize(g)(mylit))
print(finalindex)
```

Now my code gives the correct result for `max = 10**5`, but I have trouble handling very large list / numpy array.
For a list with `max = 10**15` I cannot even load the list into my memory and the calculation would go on too long.

What are some general tips to handle large lists and how to write fast(er) code for such problems?

Remark:
After reading the comments I've realised that I have to approach the problem differently. Instead of using "brute force" approach I probably use some mathematics to simplify the problem.
Still I would appreciate some tips for improving my code for larger `max`.

Comment: `10**15` elements will take eternity to complete even if you write your code in raw C.

Comment: `mylist` is a numpy array, not a list.

Comment: You can't do this by iterating over all the elements. You need to figure out a mathematical formula for it.

Comment: Remember that `np.vectorize` is a syntactic convenience: it lets you use a syntax similar to truly vectorized functions, but with none of the performance gains. Per the docs: *"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."* https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: It would be interesting to know the practical use of an an array with a Million Billion elements.

Comment: what's the origin of your `g` function?

Comment: I think this is about the perfect square. You should definitely ask in [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).